# How to create dynamic and safe queries

Tags: sql, database, dynamic

A "static" query is one that remains the same at all times. For example, the "Tags" button on Stackoverflow, or the "7 days" button on Digg. In short, they always map to a specific database query, so you can create them at design time.

But I am trying to figure out how to do "dynamic" queries where the user basically dictates how the database query will be created at runtime. For example, on Stackoverflow, you can combine tags and filter the posts in ways you choose. That's a dynamic query albeit a very simple one since what you can combine is within the world of tags. A more complicated example is if you could combine tags and users.

First of all, when you have a dynamic query, it sounds like you can no longer use the substitution api to avoid sql injection since the query elements will depend on what the user decided to include in the query. I can't see how else to build this query other than using string append.

Secondly, the query could potentially span multiple tables. For example, if SO allows users to filter based on Users and Tags, and these probably live in two different tables, building the query gets a bit more complicated than just appending columns and WHERE clauses.

How do I go about implementing something like this?

Comment: In order to suggest abstractions:
What language are you using to talk to your database?
Which database are you using?

Comment: Your database is very important. Which RDBMS? Second, are you willing to limit at all. Are you willing to say you can only search on 10 tags... 11 is verboten?

Answer (score 2):

The first rule is that users are allowed to specify *values* in SQL expressions, but not SQL *syntax*.  All query syntax should be literally specified by your code, not user input.  The values that the user specifies can be provided to the SQL as query parameters.  This is the most effective way to limit the risk of SQL injection.

Many applications need to "build" SQL queries through code, because as you point out, some expressions, table joins, order by criteria, and so on depend on the user's choices.  When you build a SQL query piece by piece, it's sometimes difficult to ensure that the result is valid SQL syntax.

I worked on a PHP class called [`Zend_Db_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) that provides an API to help with this.  If you like PHP, you could look at that code for ideas.  It doesn't handle any query imaginable, but it does a lot.

Some other PHP database frameworks have similar solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Though not a general solution, here are some steps that you can take to mitigate the dynamic yet safe query issue.

Criteria in which a column value belongs in a set of values whose cardinality is arbitrary does not need to be dynamic. Consider using either the instr function or the use of a special filtering table in which you join against. This approach can be easily extended to multiple columns as long as the number of columns is known. Filtering on users and tags could easily be handled with this approach.

When the number of columns in the filtering criteria is arbitrary yet small, consider using different static queries for each possibility.

Only when the number of columns in the filtering criteria is arbitrary and potentially large should you consider using dynamic queries. In which case...

To be safe from SQL injection, either build or obtain a library that defends against that attack. Though more difficult, this is not an impossible task. This is mostly about escaping SQL string delimiters in the values to filter for.

To be safe from expensive queries, consider using views that are specially crafted for this purpose and some up front logic to limit how those views will get invoked. This is the most challenging in terms of developer time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Well the options have to map to something.

A SQL query string `CONCAT` isn't a problem if you still use parameters for the options.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using python to access your database, I would suggest you use the [Django model system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). There are many similar apis both for python and for other languages (notably in ruby on rails). I am saving so much time by avoiding the need to talk directly to the database with SQL.

From [the example link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/):

```
#Model definition
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Model usage (this is effectively an insert statement)

```
from mysite.blog.models import Blog
b = Blog(name='Beatles Blog', tagline='All the latest Beatles news.')
b.save()
```

The queries get much more complex - you pass around a query object and you can add filters / sort elements to it. When you finally are ready to use the query, Django creates an SQL statment that reflects all the ways you adjusted the query object. I think that it is very cute.

Other advantages of this abstraction

- Your models can be created as database tables with foreign keys and constraints by Django
- Many databases are supported (Postgresql, Mysql, sql lite, etc)
- DJango analyses your templates and creates an [automatic admin site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin) out of them.